# Como aplicar Mascara dinâmica em input no angular?

Tags: angular, mask

Estou utilizando o Angular 8, exemplo de mascara seria telefone fixo e celular.

Ou seja contar a quantidade de caracteres e aplicar tal mascara.

Estou criando a mascara com o Ngx-Mask, tentando com *ngIf no html, só que não pega a condição do *ngIf, não retorna erro, só entra no else "(00) 0 0000-0000".

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>

          <ng-container *ngIf="cliente.telefone && cliente.telefone?.length <= 10; else elseTemplate">
            <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" class="form-control" formControlName='telefone'
              mask="(00) 0000-0000">
          </ng-container>

          <ng-template #elseTemplate>
            <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" class="form-control" formControlName='telefone'
              mask="(00) 0 0000-0000">
          </ng-template>
 </div>
```

Comment: se não está apresentando erro é porque sua condição no ngIf está sendo avaliada como "false". muda para *ngIf="cliente.telefone; else elseTemplate" ou *ngIf="cliente.telefone?.length <= 10; else elseTemplate" ou *ngIf="1>0; else elseTemplate" para descobrir qual condição está retornando false

Comment: *ngIf="cliente.telefone                            **false**
*ngIf="cliente.telefone?.length <= 10     **true**

Os dois juntos nunca da certo. Alguma outra dica?

Comment: não funciona para o angular material 9, funcionou outra coisa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O **ngx-mask** está funcionando normalmente, acontece que se o telefone conter espaço o seu **length** é contado com este espaço tbm, o correto é deixar o if maior ou igual a **11** dígitos se o telefone for assim por exemplo `11 1234-5678` pq, vai contar os **10** dígitos mais o espaço, pode ver o exemplo funcionando [aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask1).

```
<ng-container *ngIf="cliente.telefone && cliente.telefone?.length <= 11; else elseTemplate">
   <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" 
    class="form-control" formControlName='telefone' mask="(00) 0000-0000">
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Olhei seu exemplo e está igual o meu, não aplica a segunda mascara caso for celular: 
(00)  0 0000-0000. Viu que quero aplicar mascara se for telefone fixo ou celular.

Comment: Como é o telefone que vc recebe no seu TS isso que o importante o do Html eu já sei, como que ta ele?

Comment: É do tipo string, não sei se é exatamente o que perguntou.

Comment: Meu .ts

`
private buiderClienteForm() {
    if (this.acaoAtual === 'new') {
      this.clienteForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        nome: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
        ativo: new FormControl(true),
        telefone: [null]
});

`
meu model
public telefone?: string

Comment: Pablo vamo lá, eu preciso saber como é o valor de um telefone que recebe no seu ts: **(11)  12345678**, se é assim **11 12345678**, se é assim **1112345678**. Pode colocar um exemplo para mim ver?

Comment: Ah sim, então posso receber tanto assim: 11999999999 (11 dígitos) ou 1199999999 (10 dígitos).

Comment: Sim, isso eu fiz. O que quero é que seja dinâmico entendeu.
Tenho 1 input apenas, tanto para telefone Fixo ou Celular. 
Caso for digitado **10 dígitos = (99) 9999-9999**
Digitado **11 dígitos = (99) 9 9999-9999**

Isso que quero sacou!

Comment: Poxa cara o que vc quer não tem nada a ver com o código que postou que tem um if pra mostrar os inputs conforme a condição, mas, blza eu refiz o exemplo lá.

Comment: Estou usando formulário reativo, funciona também?
Muito obrigado.

Comment: Provavelmente deve funcionar.

Answer (score 3):

O jeito mais elegante de fzer isso é alterar o valor da mask baseado no length sem necessidade do ngIf

```
<input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" class="form-control" formControlName='telefone'
              [mask]="telMask">
```

ts:

```
telMask= '(00) 0000-0000' //comece com a que faz sentido

ngOnInit(){
  //inicializa seu form e outros codigos...
  this.seuForm.get('telefone').valueChanges.map(valor=>valor.length).subscribe(length=>{
  if(length>10){
     this.telMask='(00) 0 0000-0000'
   }else{
     this.telMask= '(00) 0000-0000'
  }

})
}
```

Comment: Eduardo tentei seu exemplo e encapsulei o **map**  

Só que não consigo digitar mais que 10 caracteres no input assim, sempre entra no **else**  

Tem alguma solução?