# Mudar o mask do input quando o valor do select for alterado

Tags: angular

Boa tarde pessoal! Eu tenho um formulário e nele eu tenho um select com as options (Telefone e Celular) e tenho também um input para o usuário preencher o numero. Eu quero que quando o usuário selecionar o option  Telefone ele aparace a mascara mask="(00) 0000-0000" e quando ele selecionar a option Celular aparecer a mask="(00) 00000-0000". Alguém consegue da um help?
Segue imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
<div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-4">
     <label class="form-label" for="">Tipo <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
         <select class="custom-select" formControlName="phoneType">
             <option value=null selected=""></option>
             <option value="1">Telefone</option>
             <option value="2">Celular</option>
         </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-12 col-sm-4 ">
  <label class="form-label" for="phone">Número <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
  <input mask="(00) 00000-0000" formControlName="phone" type="text" class="form-control" id="celular"placeholder="">                 
<div *ngIf="submitted && basicInfo.controls.phone.errors" class="text-danger">
<div *ngIf="submitted && basicInfo.controls.phone.errors">Campo obrigatório</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa minha resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/416081/como-aplicar-mascara-din%c3%a2mica-em-input-no-angular/416242#416242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde pessoal, conseguir a solução e deixarei aqui a forma a qual eu resolvi.
No próprio componente html acrescentei o seguinte código:

```
 <input  mask="{{ phone.get('phone').value.length === 11 ? '(00) 00000-0000' : '(00) 0000-00009'}}"formControlName="phone" name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
```

Obrigado!!!

Answer (score -1):

Assumindo que vc está utilizando [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask), uma solução diferente é proposta na pagina do module.

`<input mask="(00) 0000-0000||(00) 0 0000-0000" />`

Com isso a mascara se comportará como celular quando precisar de mais numeros no campo.

UPDATE:

Tente colocar o mask em um atributo e colocar na mask através de binding

`[mask]="telefone"`

E pela seleção do "Tipo" vc modifica o telefone para ser um ou outro.

Comment: não foi... 
```
 <label class="form-label" for="phone">Número <span class="text-danger">*</span> </label>
                  <input mask="(00) 0000-0000||(00) 0 0000-0000" formControlName="phone" type="text" class="form-control" id="celular"
                    placeholder=""> 
 ```